# how to use arraylist to store different string and use strings when printing text in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I want to know how to use arraylist to store different string and use strings when printing text in a textbox.

I would appreciate with anyhelp

I have done this, is there anyway to print different words as it only prints "Apple" on all the textbox. also how can I store strings on arraylist from a userinnput using textbox?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each x As TextBox In mk
        x.Text = "Apple"


    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mk.Add(TextBox1)
    mk.Add(TextBox2)
    mk.Add(TextBox3)
    mk.Add(TextBox4)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What are you trying to do?  Please post your code.

Comment: Yes I have posted my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store different strings in each textbox, you can't use the loop.  For example, you have this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each x As TextBox In mk
        x.Text = "Apple"


    Next
End Sub
```

But you'll need something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Textbox1.Text = "Apple"
    Textbox2.Text = "Banana"
    Textbox3.Text = "Pear"
    Textbox4.Text = "Strawberry"
End Sub
```

If you want to store the text in each textbox instead of the textboxes themselves, you can do this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mk.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    mk.Add(TextBox2.Text)
    mk.Add(TextBox3.Text)
    mk.Add(TextBox4.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand the first two codes but the last one how do I store it. I have inserted the strings that I wanted but it won't store?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "it won't store".

Comment: I mean in order for the strings to be stored do I need to have a listbox that shows the stored strings? The last code only allows me to type text into the texboxs , how do I show that i have stored the strings?